# I have a string '3,505.92' recognized from image, I have to convert into float, So I'm trying float('3,505.92')

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a string ***'3,505.92'*** recognized from image,
I have to convert into float, So i'm trying float('3,505.92'). But I'm getting error that saying

***could not convert string to float: '3,505.92'***

I don't want to remove comma.

Comment: *"I don't want to remove comma."* I'm not sure what to say , then. The comma isn't a valid character in a Python float.

Comment: Remove the comma from the string or live with the error. Your choice.

Comment: @SiHa Yes, This is what i am looking for. Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

You have to remove the comma if you want to convert it to float, use `string.replace()`

```py
float('3,505.92'.replace(',', ''))
```